# How to check if a property has a value in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to check if there are valid results available when a user sends a query

```
var query = req.query;
        var where = {};

        if(query.hasOwnProperty('s') && query.s.length > 0) {
            where.address = {
                $like: '%'+query.s+'%'
            };
             if(where.address.length>0 {
                console.log("Validated");
    } else {
console.log("Invalid");
        }
```

But this always returns valid no matter when query I pass in

Answer (score 0):

If a value is valid then only, it will go into the `if` block otherwise it won't go. And you are checking whether valid or not inside the `if` block which is always valid.

You could refactor this as below,

```
var query = req.query;
var where = {};
var prop = 's';

if(query[prop] && query[prop].length > 0) {
  where.address = {
     $like: '%' + query[prop] + '%'
  };
}

if(where.address) {
 console.log('Validated');
} else {
  console.log('Invalid');
}
```